# Oddity of static:: calling a method that contains $this

Tags: php, static, this, self

In this example I get the fatal error "Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context" as expected

```
class ctis_parent{
    public function objFunc(){
        var_dump('Called succes');
    }

    public static function call(){

        $this->objFunc(); 
    }

    public function __construct(){
        self::call();
    }

}

new ctis_parent();
```

But if remove static keyword from definition of call() method all work fine, why?

```
class ctis_parent{
    public function objFunc(){
        var_dump('Called succes');
    }

    public  function call(){
        $this->objFunc();
    }

    public function __construct(){
        self::call();
    }

}

new ctis_parent(); 

//string 'Called succes' (length=13)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're using `$this` when you're not in an object. Well, you're not REALLY, but with the static declaration, people could do:

```
ctis_parent::call();
```

Where, `$this` would be illegal.

See the [docs for static](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php).

Comment: I know that I use static in the wrong context but why in the second example it works?

Comment: @yurisnk: Why shouldn't it work? After the constructor is magically called, $this exists, and you're calling it's function objFunc();

Comment: @yurisnk: when you're calling from the constructor, you're calling from a method that can only be invoked when a new instance is being created, so there is a `$this`, and calling a method (that you didn't declare static) statically from within the instance is just fine

Comment: @elias-van-ootegem it means that when we call the non static method with the static:: keyword this is equivalent to calling with $this-> ?

Comment: Yes, sort of but `::` is what is called a _scope resolution operator_, so `self::call()` just means call function `call` in the scope of `self::`. On the whole, it's better left for use of statics, to avoid confusion. I was rather surprized to see that `self::nonstaticMethod()` worked. I thought it didn't anymore...

Answer (score 1):

A static function, by definition doesn't need the class being instantiated, so it doesn't have access to the `$this->` reference, which points to the current instance. If an instance doesn't exist, it can't be pointed to. Makes sense.